# Session Not Carry Over to another page in https server php

Tags: php, session, https, sessionid

I developed one site with session. Its works in Local server and Also in Production machine. Now they move the site to new server with SSL HTTPs . Here i face one problem .

Session set in one page but not carry over to another page. Same code works in http based server.

I tried the following methods to resolve this but not yet it solved

1) I pass the session id over url and set in another page. Here also SESSION not set.

2) I use this two lines in my php file as some one suggested in some forums

ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

3) I also use these lines also to resolve  as some one suggested in some forums 
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'https://xxx.com');

session_set_cookie_params(ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime'), ini_get('session.cookie_path'), 'https://xxx.com');

4)In PHP.ini, follwing things under session is shown

session.auto_start  Off Off

session.bug_compat_42   Off Off

session.bug_compat_warn Off Off

session.cache_expire    180 180

session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache

session.cookie_domain   no value    no value

session.cookie_httponly Off Off

session.cookie_lifetime 0   0

session.cookie_path /   /

session.cookie_secure   Off Off

session.entropy_file    no value    no value

session.entropy_length  0   0

session.gc_divisor  1000    1000

session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440

session.gc_probability  1   1

session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5

session.hash_function   0   0

session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID

session.referer_check   no value    no value

session.save_handler    files   files

session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session

session.serialize_handler   php php

session.use_cookies On  On

session.use_only_cookies    Off Off

session.use_trans_sid   0   0

Following Error Message shown in server 
Undefined index: userid in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/HomePage.php on line 9

Still I have same problem.  Please suggest me to resolve this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the data being lost when the user transfers from the http: url to the https version?I believe I've read that the switch in the url can cause the session data to be reset, and the server to see this as a new session.

Comment: Also, I believe that switching from yoursite.com to www.yoursite.com will cause the session to be lost as well, since sessions don't carry over subdomains, and www. is a subdomain.

Comment: Is there any way to resolve? Instead of session how to handle? Here i am not using any subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here They give Vhost server. Vhost server doesn's store sessions. So only only i face this problem.. I use oneway to resolve this problem. Pass session as POST variable and assign the session id in each page. Now it works..

Answer (score 0):

You've given some information about changes you've made to afect the outcome, but you've not provided any details of the diagnostics you've done to identify the problem.

Have you chacked that the browser is returning the session cookie? Have you checked that a session file exists? Does the session span http and https? If so, do the vhosts run under different uids?

```
<?php

print_r($_COOKIE);

if ($_COOKIE[sesion_name()]) {
    $path=ini_get('session.save_path') . '/' . $_COOKIE[sesion_name()];
    if (!is_readable(dirname($path)) || !is_dir(dirname($path))) {
      print "bad session dir\n";
    }
    if (!is_readable($path) || !is_file($path)) {
      print "bad session file\n";
    } else if (!is_writeable($path)) {
      print "permissions issue with session file\n";
    }
    print_r(stat($path));
    print "\n\n";
    print @file_get_contents($path);
} else {
    print "no session cookie";
}
```